# JS / jQuery - Extend Var in each()-function

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

I have two lists in this format:

```
<ul id="filters" class="option-set button-group" data-filter-group="kategorie">
    <li>
        <a href="#" data-filter=".corporatedesign">Corporate Design</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" data-filter=".webdesign">Webdesign</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

In Javascript there is a click-function which addes or removes the class "isotopeactive" to the link-element:

```
$('#filters a').click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);                
    if ( $this.hasClass('isotopeactive') ) {
        $this.removeClass('isotopeactive');
    }else{
        $this.addClass('isotopeactive');
    }
```

The problem is to get all the data-filter - data from all elements that are "isotopeactive" into one variable. My first try was this, but it does not work..

```
var filterValue = '';
var i = 0;  

$( ".isotopeactive" ).each(function() {
    filterValue += $this.attr('data-filter');
    i++;
});
```

In the end i want to get something like this:
filterValue => ".corporatedesign .webdesign"

Any suggestions? Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```
var data = $('.isotopeactive').map(function(){
             return this.dataset.filter;
           }).get();
```

For those, older, browsers that don't implement `dataset`:

```
var data = $('.isotopeactive').map(function(){
             return this.getAttribute('data-filter');
           }).get();
```

Or:

```
var data = $('.isotopeactive').map(function(){
             return $(this).data('filter');
           }).get();
```

This will return an array of values to the `data` variable.

References:

- JavaScript:

  - [`Element.getAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getAttribute).
  - [`HTMLElement.dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.dataset).
- jQuery:

  - [`data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/).
  - [`get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/).
  - [`map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/).

Comment: You're very welcome indeed, I'm glad to have helped! :)